# Can I initial a static global variable by calling a function in C language?

Tags: c, static

Can I initial a static global variable by calling a function in C language? For example:

```
static int var_01 = fun();
```

When I use this in VC6 it succeed. But it failed in GCC 4.6.1.
This is very strange. I guess this usage is illegal in C89? Or other reason cause this?

Comment: You'll need to initialise it to a compile-time constant, so in general no.  (Perhaps yes if your function is actually a macro.)

Comment: @sapi The fun() is an ordinory function.It's strange that it can compile ok with VC6.

Comment: @Ezio: Are you sure you are compiling it as C, as opposed to C++? It is valid in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @AndreyT I edit this in C file,so I think it should be in C.But as you said,I guess VC may compile it with C++ features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C99 and as far as I know in C89 as well an initializer for an object with static storage duration has to be either a constant expression or an string literal, from the draft C99 standard section `6.7.8` *Initialization*:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

and a function call is not a constant expression from section `6.6` *Constant expressions* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Constant expressions **shall not contain** assignment, increment,
>   decrement, **function-call**, or comma operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.98)

`gcc` generates the same error using both `-std=c99` and `-std=c89`, note I am also using the following flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

In the modern versions of Visual Studio compiler this does not work in C(*[see it live](http://rextester.com/WSIBH20775)*) but in C++ this does work. So it may be that you are compiling it as C++ in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Because your post is tagged with c. In c, this is a compile error. You must initialize that to constat literals.

See: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-80/